# how can i use watir to test ruby chosen dropdown list jquery

Tags: ruby, jquery-plugins, watir, jquery-chosen

I need to test a ruby page which has some chosen dropdown list and i don't succeed to select an option from the list. the options are not shown in firebug until i choose one of them.
can anyone help?

Comment: What have you tried? Please share the code. Also, please share link to the page, or a similar one, or relevant HTML.

Comment: the page is in the internal network of my company and i can't export it. the problem is that the values of the list are hidden and the watir can't select it like i do in normal select list

Comment: Is it an autocomplete control rather than a select list - for example the jquery one - http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/.

Comment: @EyalGolan: http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/12/not-providing-html-page-is-bogus.html

Comment: yes, it has auto complete. can it help me?

Comment: its a jquery chosen standard select - as seen in this page: http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: @EyalGolan: can you provide the code that reproduces the problem with the public link that you have found?

Comment: i don't have a specific bug, i just don't know how to make the Watir to work with this list and chose the desire line. i couldn't find any reference to this in the web.

Answer (score 0):

This will make the dropdown to appear:

```
require "watir-webdriver"
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto "http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/"
browser.div(id: "selEA2_chzn").a.click
```

Comment: great. but how do i select one item from the list?

Comment: i have tried to select or set one of the values and nothing worked

Comment: for example: <li id="sel2ZV_chzn_o_4" class="active-result" style="">Aland Islands</li>. i want to tell the watir to pick this line by the name of the country which i don't understand how to do it...

Comment: Try this: `browser.li(:text => "Aland Islands").click`